# DataTable Timeout

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I'm using a DataTable to display data but the data query fails. Here's the DataTable code:

```
$('#table_id').DataTable( {
    ajax:{ 
        url: './datasource02.php'
    },
    "columns": [
        { "data": "name",       "name": "name",       "title": "Name", },
        { "data": "email",      "name": "email",      "title": "Email" },
        { "data": "coupon_id",  "name": "coupon_id",  "title": "Coupon" },
        { "data": "coupon_off", "name": "coupon_off", "title": "Discount" },
    ],
    "dom": 'lfrtipB',
    "destroy": 'true',
    "buttons": {
       "dom": {
           "button": {
                "tag": "button",
                "className": "btn"
            }
        },
        "buttons": [ 
            { extend: 'copy', text: 'Copy' },
            { extend: 'csv', text: 'CSV' },
            { extend: 'excel', text: 'Excel' }, 
            { extend: 'pdf', text: 'PDF' }, 
            { extend: 'print', text: 'Print' } 
        ]   
    }
} );
```

The error I'm getting is:

DataTables warning: table id=table_id - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

datasource02.php?_=1510684591408

Request Method:GET

Status Code:404 Not Found

Initiator: jquery.min.js:4

Comment: Post your actual data query from datasource02.php - the AJAX call is not returning valid data so the issue is most likely in that file

Comment: Check the path to your `datasource02.php` is correct. It's returning a 404 status (not invalid data as @bhttoan has stated).

Comment: 404 Not Found, means, the path to the file is not correct or file doesn't exists on the server. Please check the `Diagnosis` part at http://datatables.net/tn/7 to diagnose the issue.

Comment: Can someone suggest how to fix the 404 error? I'm using cPanel on the server. Also, when I try to access the data source file directly in my browser via http://<hostname>.com/datasource02.php I get a "file not found error".

Comment: Do you have a `include` or `include_once` in your `datasource02.php`?

Comment: I'm using the Stripe API php library so I've got: require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/stripe-php/init.php');

Comment: @muaaz Could the issue be the URL I'm using? Would this resolve it: url: '<fullpath>/datasource02.php'

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the information provided is not enough to guide you for the solution, e.g: you haven't provided the directory structure.
Below are few questions.

1. Where the file `datasource02.php` located (Path to the file in server)?
2. File Path, that has the above code?
3. Which CMS you are using?

So, definitely 404 is a URL problem and it means, the file you are looking for doesn't exist.

**Debug Suggestion:** You can open the file `http://website.com/path/to/datasource02.php` in Address bar to see if that gives `200` response. Also modify the code as below.

```
$('#table_id').DataTable( {
    ajax:{ 
        url: 'http://website.com/path/to/datasource02.php'
    },
    "columns": [
        { "data": "name",       "name": "name",       "title": "Name", },
        { "data": "email",      "name": "email",      "title": "Email" },
        { "data": "coupon_id",  "name": "coupon_id",  "title": "Coupon" },
        { "data": "coupon_off", "name": "coupon_off", "title": "Discount" },
    ],
    "dom": 'lfrtipB',
    "destroy": 'true',
    "buttons": {
       "dom": {
           "button": {
                "tag": "button",
                "className": "btn"
            }
        },
        "buttons": [ 
            { extend: 'copy', text: 'Copy' },
            { extend: 'csv', text: 'CSV' },
            { extend: 'excel', text: 'Excel' }, 
            { extend: 'pdf', text: 'PDF' }, 
            { extend: 'print', text: 'Print' } 
        ]   
    }
} );
```